# How can I trigger a SwiftUI alert from app in response to an async query (user notification authorization)

Tags: swift, testing, swiftui, concurrency

I'm looking for the solution to a specific problem but also wouldn't mind some general advice. The last iOS project I built was in Objective-C. I'm in Swift 5.1 targeting iOS 13.3

My app relies heavily on UserNotifications. It's useless without the permission. So when the user updates our Reminder instance and triggers my save function (to disk and generate notifications), I want to re-check their permissions and prompt them to visit settings if permissions have not been granted. Simple, right?

Well, the prompt to grant permission only appears the first time I ask for it. So I need to trigger an alert on a negative result to that call. I'd just change a @State variable in my App, but I'm in a closure on init, in an async context; system isn't having it.

When our user updates the Reminder model and triggers the save action below, I get doubled up errors about escaping closures capturing a mutating 'self' parameter. I get it; I need to wrap that in some container object I hold by reference. That container object should maybe trigger some closures I feed it? I've tried a couple refactors and started getting the purple runtime error about how changing binding variables outside of the main thread won't trigger an update (I think even on @MainActor though that code is gone now).

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UserNotifications

class NotificationManager: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate { // ObservableObject
static let shared = NotificationManager()

    override private init() {}
    
    // #MARK - UNNotificationCenterDelegate methods
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {
        print(center)
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(response)
        completionHandler()
    }

}

@main
struct ReminderApp: App {
@ObservedObject private var reminder: Reminder
//    @ObservedObject private var notificationManager = NotificationManager.shared

    @MainActor @State var shouldRequestAuthorization: Bool = false
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var persistAction: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    
    init() {
        let reminder = Reminder.loadOrCreate()
        self._reminder = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: reminder)
        
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = NotificationManager.shared
        notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // TODO: trigger this more
        
        func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) async throws {
            // TODO: Not re-appearing after first refusal, link user to settings in Alert..
            Task {
                let authorized = try await notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert])
                completion(authorized)
            }
        }
        
        self.persistAction = {
            try! reminder.save()
    
            // Escaping closure captures mutating self parameter
            Task { @MainActor in
                try await requestAuthorization { authorized in
                    self.shouldRequestAuthorization = authorized
                }
            }
            
            notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    
            if reminder.enabled {
                // Schedule notifications...
            }
        }
        
        
        reminder
            .objectDidChange
            .sink(receiveValue: persistAction!)
            .store(in: &cancellables)

//
//        notificationManager
//            .objectDidChange
//            .sink(receiveValue: ...)
//            .store(in: &cancellables)

    }
    
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(reminder)
                .padding(Edge.Set(arrayLiteral: [.horizontal, .vertical]), 50)
                .alert(isPresented: $shouldRequestAuthorization) {
                    let settingsButton = Alert.Button.default(Text("Go to Settings")) {
                        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                            return
                        }
    
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    
                    return Alert(title: Text("Notifications Permission Needed"),
                          message: Text("Our app needs this to send reminders"),
                          primaryButton: settingsButton,
                          secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if phase == .background {
                // Perform cleanup when all scenes within
                // MyApp go to the background.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The references are out of date and the problem is complicated enough that I figure asking you fine folks for a little help is my fastest option. Shouldn't this be simpler?

I'm happy to adapt my NotificationsManager to use as my container object (previously this was just called NotificationsDelegate)

Comment: You are mixing completion handlers, combine and async/await.  You should pick 1 of those and stick with it. OnReceive is the SwiftUI way of handling publishers if absolutely required but you should not mix all these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just get tunnel vision and your brain shuts down. After a break I'm back to answer my own question. I turned the saveAction into a function. Duh. I had gotten it into my head that .sink required a variable name, wouldn't take a method name. It would.

Code is not fully tested but I hope this is helpful for anyone facing similar trouble.

```
struct ReminderApp: App {
    @ObservedObject private var reminder: Reminder
    
    @MainActor @State var shouldRequestAuthorization: Bool = false
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        let reminder = Reminder.loadOrCreate()
        self._reminder = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: reminder)
        
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = NotificationManager.shared
        notificationCenter.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // TODO: trigger this more
        
        reminder
            .objectDidChange
            .sink(receiveValue: saveAction)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
    }
    
    func saveAction() {
        try! reminder.save()
    
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
//        shouldRequestAuthorization = false
        
        Task { //@MainActor in
            do {
                let authorized = try await notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert])
                shouldRequestAuthorization = !authorized
            } catch {
                print(error)
                #warning("hey")
//                        fatalError(error)
            }

        }
        
        if reminder.enabled {
        // ...
        }
    }
    
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(reminder)
                .padding(Edge.Set(arrayLiteral: [.horizontal, .vertical]), 50)
                .alert(isPresented: $shouldRequestAuthorization) {
                    shouldRequestAuthorization = false
                    // TODO: encapsulate this
                    return Alert(title: Text("Notifications Permission Needed"),
                                 message: Text("Our app needs this to send reminders"),
                                 primaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("Go to Settings")) {
                        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                            })
                        }
                    },
                    secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }.task {
                    saveAction()
                }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if phase == .background {
                // Perform cleanup when all scenes within
                // MyApp go to the background.
            }
        }
    }

}
```